# access react route params in server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, reactjs, express

i came up with this problem with ReactJS and ExpressJS: So basically user uploads some info on `/info` route with React & axios. then user gets route params from server side to redirect to:

```
axios.post('/info', SomeData)
.then(res => res.data)
.then(data =>{ 
  window.location.replace(`/info/${data.id}`)
})
```

this is piece of cake but when user redirects to that page problem occurs, i need to get data from that page. i can get route params and perform request on client side like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    axios.get(`/api/info/${params.id}`)      
}
```

but how can i get request on server side? how can express access that "id" to search it in database and query data with it to send back to client? like:

```
app.get('/api/info/:id', async (req,res)=>{
   await db.find({id: req.params.id}, (data) =>{
      res.status(200).send({data})
   })
})
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the component itself same as the `GET` use your param and call your service same thing to `POST`

```
postUserInfo = () => { 
  const userInfo ={};
  axios.post(`/api/info/${params.id}`,userInfo).then(()=>{
      console.log("user info posted");
  })
}
```

**Example:**

```
 <Form onSubmit={this.postUserInfo}> </form>
```

Comment: i saw the update so you should use the service from the client side and get it from the back end there is no other way.

Comment: but how? how does server knows what that "id" is

Comment: from the component itself  you will use `params.id` that you have mentioned in the `componentDidMount`